# UsbDeviceConnection bulktransfer not working properly

Tags: java, android, connection, usb

I need a help to understand how UsbDeviceConnection bulktransfer works. For example I do not understand what is TIMEOUT good for? I changed it to different values, but I do not see any differences in received data.

Here I have a small testing code:

```
public static void read2(){

    r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                final int SIZE = 4096;
                send("M?");
                while (true) {

                    if (mUsbManager.hasPermission(device)){


                        byte[] buffer = new byte[SIZE];

                        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

                        if (connection.bulkTransfer(epIn, buffer, SIZE, 0) >= 0) {
                            for (int i = 2; i < SIZE; i++) {
                                if (buffer[i] != 0) {
                                    str.append((char) buffer[i]);
                                } else {
                                    Log.e("Database", "M=" + str.toString());
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            Log.e("Database", "M=" + str.toString());
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    };
    thread = new Thread(r);
    thread.start();
}

public static void send(String command){
    String fullCommand = "@" + command + "\r\n"; /*+ "\r\n"*/

    bytes = fullCommand.getBytes();

    while (connection==null){
        continue;
    }
    connection.bulkTransfer(epOut, bytes, bytes.length, 100); //0
}
```

Here I try to send a command to an USB device, and then it sends me back a string. That string should be about 25 character long, but the result what I get is different, sometimes 2 characters, sometimes 5, but I do not get the whole string.

I tried to change the buffers size, the timeout, the Thread.sleep() waiting time, but nothing solved my problem.

Could anybody help me to understand how this whole thing works, where can be the problem and how should I set these variables to get a functioning code?

Answer (score 2):

Size of data in bulk transfer is limited by device. Right value You get by calling method `Endpoint.getMaxPacketSize()`. And You must split data to pieces with this maximum size and send sequentially.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - but... I‘m sending way less data per command than the 64bytes that are that maximum package size